# Unable to connect to SQLEXPRESS using machinename

Tags: mysql

I am able to connect to SQL EXPRESS USING local but I am unable to connect using machine name. I wanted to test remote connection . I tried to restart the services but it is not helping .

It gives error 26

Also, if I use the pc-name using windows authentication it works fine but if I use SQL Server authentication it fails with error 18456 . So it looks to be issue with specific user which works fine with local but not with pc-name while doing SQL Server Authentication ( I have already checked and confirmed that both windows and sql server authentication is enabled )

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be issue with user properties. It is fixed now . Thanks.